# Double integrals in polar coordinates with unexpected result

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I have been working on an exercise where I need to convert to polar coordinates :

$$\iint_R (x+y)\,dA\,,$$

where $$R=\left\{(x,y)\mid 1\le x^2+y^2\le 4\,,\, x\le 0\right\}$$

To me, it makes perfect sense that $ (x + y)\,dx\,dy $ became : $(r\cos(\theta) + r\sin(\theta))r\,dr\,d\theta$

What I don't understand is that, I was expecting to work between $r = -1$ and $r = -2$ ; $\theta = - \pi/2$ and $\theta = \pi/2$

Instead, the solution puts $r = 1$ and $r = 2$ ;
$\theta = \pi/2$ and $\theta = 3\pi/2$

**Could you tell me why ? (I am trying to grasp this new concept)**

Comment: $x \leq 0$ means second and third quadrant.

Comment: Also direction is decided by $\theta$ and not $r$.

Comment: Why make  things simple when it's so simple to make them complicated?

Comment: $r$ should be always non-negative.

Comment: You *could* in principle use negative values for $r$, but then you would have to write $dxdy=|r|drd\theta$. If you want to make your life simple, *never* use negative $r$.

Comment: What would you do if the condition were $y \geq 0$ instead of $x\leq 0$? Half of that region overlaps half the region in the original question.

Comment: Indeed. The change of variable can still be done the way you did it, but it may end with a wrong *orientation*. (If you take negative $r$, the orientation of small pieces of this area obtained by slight increases of $r$ and $\theta$ is *opposite* of the orientation of the pieces obtained by slight increases of $x$ and $y$ - with the effect that, unexpectedly, you will end with the value of the integral that is correct in magnitude but of the wrong sign.). That is the reason for the *modulus* $|r|$ from @HansLundmark 's comment.

Comment: @DavidK, we would work on the first and second quadrants right ?

Comment: Yes, quadrants I and II, but what values of $r$?

Comment: @DavidK : following my old logic, I would have said : -2≤r≤-1 and 1≤r≤2
Since all of you have told me that r should be non negative, I would go for : 1≤r≤2
The choice of the r is still confusing for me whereas theta is 100% clear

Comment: It isn't clear to me at all why you would use $\theta$ in the range $-\pi/2\leq\theta\leq0$ for points in quadrant II (as you did in the question) unless you had some misguided notion that angles in polar coordinates can never be more than a right angle. For the region with $y\geq 0$ I would immediately think of $0\leq\theta\leq\pi,$ after which you have to use only positive values of $r$ (because negative values would land you in quadrants III or IV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this drawing can help you in understanding the solution

[image]

To integrate the purlple area you have to chose a radius in

$$1<r<2$$

and a corresponding angle in

$$\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi=\frac{3}{2}\pi$$

Thus rotating this positive radius in the angle's interval you get exactly the desired area to integrate

Comment: Thank you so much. It is now clear !

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ cannot be negative... It represents the distance to the origin. The condition $1\leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ puts our domain between the circles with radius 1 and 2, and so $r \in[1,2]$. The condition $x \leq 0$ puts our domain in the second and third quadrants, for which $\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Comment: Thank your for the kind reminder of the value of r